# Get the value of an environment variable whose name is stored in a variable

Tags: powershell, environment-variables, indirection

I am trying to figure out an easy to read and understandable idiom that evaluates the the value of an environment variable whose name is stored in a variable:

```
$varName='TEMP'
```

I have come up with

```
$val = invoke-expression "`$env:$varName"
```

and am wondering if there is a more to the point alternative.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`env:` a real PSDrive that supports item retrieval:

```
$val = (Get-Item -Path env:\$varName).Value
```