# How two concatenate environment variables names in powershell

Tags: powershell, environment-variables, indirection

Say I have the following **environment** variables:

```
a = Poke
b = mon
Pokemon= Feraligatr
```

I want to be able to concatenate `a` and `b` **environment** variables to get the variable name `Pokemon` and the get `Pokemon` value like `$($env:ab)` or `$($env:$($env:a)$($env:b))` (This examples does not work)

Comment: What do environment variables do in your code? Read [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_environment_variables?view=powershell-7.3) article please. What you want to do requires [reflection](https://blog.ironmansoftware.com/daily-powershell/dotnet-reflection-powershell/). Please explain WHY exactly you want to do this. What is the purpose of your code.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get the value of an environment variable whose name is stored in a variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69311346/get-the-value-of-an-environment-variable-whose-name-is-stored-in-a-variable) The answer is `(Get-Item -Path env:\$(($env:a)+($env:b))).Value`

Comment: @Max They do not do anything special, they are just two (`a` and `b`) strings passed as parameters and set as environment variables, in order to the get `Pokemon` environment  variable I need to concatenate this two first and key try to get the variable value,

Comment: The sub-expressions are not needed. Simply do `(Get-Item env:$env:a$env:b).Value`. This is easier to read in an editor that does proper syntax highlighting. Alternatively `(Get-Item env:"$env:a$env:b").Value`

Comment: That code isn't powershell.

Answer (score 1):

Building on the helpful comments:

You're looking for *indirection*, i.e. the ability to refer to an environment variable *indirectly*, via *another* (environment) variable(s) storing the target variable's *name*.

---

**PowerShell-idiomatic solution**:

Use the `Env:` [drive](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Providers) in combination with the [`Get-Content`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-content) cmdlet:

```bash
# The target environment variable.
$env:Pokemon='bingo!'

# The variables that, in combination, return the *name* 
# of the target environment variable.
$env:a = 'Poke'
$env:b = 'mon'

# Use Get-Content and the env: drive to retrieve
# an environment variable by an *indirectly* specified name.
# Note: 
#   * env:$env:a$env:b is treated like "env:$env:a$env:b",
#     i.e. an expandable (interpolating string).
#   * For better visual delineation of the variables, use:
#       env:${env:a}${env:b}
#   * `-ErrorAction Ignore` ignores the case when the target var.
#     doesn't exist (quietly returns $null`)
# -> 'bingo!'
Get-Content -ErrorAction Ignore env:$env:a$env:b 

# Alternative, with explicit string concatenation.
Get-Content -ErrorAction Ignore ('env:' + $env:a + $env:b)
```

Note:

- To *set* environment variables indirectly, use the [`Set-Content`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/set-content) cmdlet; e.g.:

  ```bash
  $varName = 'FOO'
  Set-Content env:$varName BAR # $env:FOO now contains 'BAR'
  ```
- Applying the same technique to regular *shell* variables (non-environment variables), requires either use of the `variable:` drive, or, for more flexibility, the [`Get-Variable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/get-variable) and [`Set-Variable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/set-variable) cmdlets - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68214332/45375).
- More more information about expandable (interpolating) string literals such as `"env:$env:a$env:b"`, see the conceptual [about_Quoting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Quoting_Rules#double-quoted-strings) help topic.

---

**.NET API alternative**:

As [Max](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13523921/max) points out, you can also use the static [`System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable) .NET method:

```bash
[Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable("${env:a}${env:b}")
```

For more information about calling .NET API methods from PowerShell, see the conceptual [about_Methods](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Methods) help topic.

Comment: Can't you just use the following in powershell? `[Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable("$($env:a)$($env:b)")`. That should work as long as the variables already exist, right?

Comment: @Max, yes, good point, thanks - I've added your suggestion to your answer.